# SQL Server : Apostrophe in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server query from third party like:

```
SELECT * FROM SC.TOY T WHERE T.IS_SMALL != N'Y' AND T.NAME = 'TRUCK'
```

I am confused about usage of apostrophe after N and Y. Can someone please help me explaining what does it exactly means?

Comment: http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-some-sql-strings-have-an-n-prefix.html

Comment: Amazing, this was quick. So N stands for National language character set and helps in converting CHAR to NCHAR, and TEXT as NTEXT and VARCHAR to NVARCHAR. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It doesn't convert. `N` specifies a NVARCHAR or NCHAR value. Quotes without a preceding N define a VARCHAR or CHAR value.

Comment: Not sure why -1, I am new bie to SQL Server and trying to learn things and I did google like -- "SQL Server apostrophe in where"

Answer (score 1):

It means that the 'Y' is stored in a table either as either ntext, nchar, nvarchar

Comment: Since 'Y' looks like a CHAR, above query is searching for Y which is instance of NCHAR?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has `char` and `varchar` as types where each character is represented by one byte. Unicode types are `nchar` and `nvarchar` (as in native char or national language character set) where charactes are represented by two bytes per character. If one has to assign or give some literal text it is necessary to indicate which type of text it is. So

```
   'Hello' is a  char literal
  N'Hello' is a nchar literal
```

Comment: This is helpful example. Dust is cleared now from my brain :)